# How to save value from text file into an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save the 4 values that has a .txt into an array, something like this:

```
array = [12.3,32.2,5.6,7.0];
```

I have seen multiple examples on internet. Most of them have a button to select the file you want to read, but my file is always the same `"/path/to_file/file.txt"`, so I don't want to select any other.

I have found a code that works more or less, but I don't know how to save the values of the file into an array. My code is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Read File (via AJAX)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'Contact.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents;
    reader.send(null);
}

function displayContents() {
    if(reader.readyState==4) {
        var el = document.getElementById('main');
        el.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" value="test.txt"  onclick="loadFile()" />
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The format of the .txt file is this:

```
12.3

32.2

5.6

7.0
```

If anyone can give any suggestion to save the values into an array I would be very grateful. As I am a beginner with HTML and Javascript any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do let us know the format of text files which you have!

Comment: Updated with file format

Comment: Can you show me the response of reader.responseText

Comment: Yeah, the output is 12.3 32.2 5.6 7.0

Comment: then can you show me the response of  reader.responseText.split(" ");

Comment: sorry @UllasHunka for waiting. The output of  reader.responseText.split(" "); is the same as the output of reader.responseText;

Comment: @Andermutu added ad mini-parser for your given file-content in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite `displayContents()` function like this:

```js
function displayContents()
{
    if(reader.readyState == 4)
    {
        var array = reader.responseText.split(/\s+/);

        // we convert all strings into numbers:
        array = array.map(function(v){return +v});

        console.log(array); // [12.3, 32.2, 5.6, 7]

        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = array;
    }
}
```

**Only to demonstrate how it works:**

We have in `textarea` the same value like in your text file. And because of this I use `textarea` only for demonstration.

```js
var array = document.getElementById('tarea').value.split(/\s+/);

// we convert strings into numbers:
array = array.map(function(v){return +v});

console.log(array); // [12.3, 32.2, 5.6, 7]
```

```html
<textarea id="tarea" rows="5" cols="25">12.3

32.2

5.6

7.0</textarea>
```

The last number `7.0` is for computer like a number `7`. If you want have it like `7.0` then you have not to convert it to number.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have replaced displayContents() function like you mentioned but when I try the program it doesn't display anything. If you need more information ask please and thank you.

Comment: @Andermutu, do you have nothing in the console and nothing in main div? If it is so, then write me here in comment your code of displayContents() function please.

Comment: When I run the program I get this error message: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. I have discovered now that there is a console on html...

Comment: @Andermutu, I have corrected my code and have cheched it on my server. You can use it now.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! It works perfectly and now I have the values of the file saved in the array.

Comment: @Andermutu, enjoy it! Now you could use improved code too.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for given file-content**

```js
var text_from_file = "12.3\n\
\n\
32.2\n\
\n\
5.6\n\
\n\
7.0";

var out = text_from_file.split(/\s+/); // split by whitespace (newline included)
console.log(out);
```

**Original Answer**

You can only read a file, which is accessible from your browser.

`reader.open('get', <URI>, true);`

For `<URI>` you cant place a filepath like `/src/files/myfile.txt` it has to be a file accessible for the browser like `http://127.0.0.1/myFile.txt`

To read the file content as an array, you can use [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).

```
var array = ["Hello","World"];
var array_as_text = JSON.stringify(array); // Returns a string which you store in your file
var array_from_text = JSON.parse(array_as_text);
```

If you have a specific format in your file (you will have to provide an example for this). You will need to parse the file-content.
So if you need further help, please provide the file content of your `.txt`